# Predicting MySQLi server returns for error handling

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, mysqli

I'm working on a HTML5 CSS3 jQuery Mobile Cordova/PhoneGap application.

The first page is a login which takes the username & password and runs it through a PHP script on my server to connect to the SQL database.

It all works but I can't seem to handle incorrect logins correctly. Because its a cordova app the cross-domain issue is overcome by using the JSONP plugin so any information returning from the server has to be formatted in JSON or the ajax will throw an error.

Even if i suppress the default error message when the login by use of:
error_reporting(0); 
or
perpending @ to mysqlconnect / select db variables (not functions themselves)

the server will still return garbage:

```
    Reload the page to get source for: http://www.heatingassets.com/authenticate.php?jsoncallback=jQuery111209247028061671368_1428682105651
   &usrnm=xxxxx&pswd=xxxxx&_=142868210565
```

in an obviously non JSON format screwing up the ajax.

Is there anything I can do to completely stop anything returning from the server apart from exactly only what i encode and return?

And on a side not, if anyone knows of a more secure way to pass username/password information to the server I'd appreciate it!

UPDATE:

The above return from the server is the response sent when error_reporting(0) is included in the php file, otherwise is returns what you mention in the comments.

js:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.heatingassets.com/authenticate.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: '5000',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data){
           if(data['success'] == true){

               $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#pagetwo", {
                allowSamePageTransition:true
            });

           } else if (data['success'] == false){
               if(data['errors']['combo']){

                   if(data['errors']['opendb']){
                       alert('There was a problem opening the database :(');
                   } else {
                       alert('Incorrect login combo bro!');
                   }

               }

           }


        },
        error: function(){
                alert("First ajax function error");

        }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type'); 

    session_start();

    $errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
    $data           = array();      // array to pass back data



    $username = $_REQUEST['usrnm'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['pswd'];

    $database = "u727397756_hadb";
    $server = "mysql.hostinger.co.uk";
    $con = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password);
    $opendb = mysqli_select_db($con, $database);
        if(!$con) {
            $errors['combo'] = 'Incorrect user pass combo. ';
        };  

        if(!$opendb){
            $errors['opendb'] = 'Could not open the database.';
        }
    if ( ! empty($errors)) {
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
    } else {
        $data['success'] = true;


        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        mysqli_close($con);

        echo $_REQUEST['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($data) . ');';
    }
?>
```

Comment: you need to return from the PHP that the login attempt failed.. Can you show some of your work ?

Comment: _“the server will still return garbage: Reload the page to get source for […]”_ – that is _not_ the actual return when the mentioned URL is called – it returns a PHP warning saying _“Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'10.2.1.41' (using password: YES) in […] Warning:  mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in […]”_ instead. So what you want to do is implement some _proper error handling_ for such cases, instead of letting PHP spit out warnings.

Comment: (Whether you want to pass actual database credentials over the net, would be a different question. You did not go into specifics as to what kind of app you are creating here – but usually users of a web app are not authenticated against the database _itself_, but by comparing user data that is stored _in_ the database [so that only the PHP script doing that check holds the DB credentials, server-side].)

Comment: I've updated to add the code. the original return was as you said a warning saying the user/pass combo was incorrect. But with php error reporting turned off, it still sent that 'garbage'. the problem is the incorect formatting, but i'm not sure how i could handle the error in the PHP in order to format it in JSON then pass to javascript to take appropriate action.

Comment: Do you really want to have a separate _database user_ for every user of your application?

Comment: Each page in the application renders dynamically depending on specific information a user provides during initialisation, and is constantly updated and modified, which changes the application each time its opened / loaded. 
Meaning a database on the server would have to be unique to the user hence seperate database users, this is just the concept I've thought up logically but if theres other / easier ways to do it i'd appreciate the tip!